# How to dynamically check if the file or directory exists while user is typing in Winform TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to create a TextBox in windows form application to check if the file or directory exists. Normally, it is really simple using `File.Exist() or Directory.Exist()` although how can I give it a functionality to perform this check while user is still typing in a TextBox?

Specifically, I mean to do this dynamically, if the directory or file exists then activate a certain button or do something else. It might also be possible to wait for the user to stop and perform the check in a fraction of a seconds.

Ultimately, let the user write directory or file path in a TextBox, wait for 1 second after user stops (to avoid unnecessary processing on every key input), then perform the check and if success enable the button. So, it makes it kind of a dynamic process.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. What have you tried?

Comment: I think most of us implement an event handler for the TextBox on `KeyUp` or `KeyPress` events, depending on what your needs are. Not sure if you really need to wait that 1 second.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, a bit fancy though :-)
I tried events like Keydown but would like to know some efficient and more intelligent way to do this.

Comment: @code4life Yes, I did, as I said, is there any other efficient way to do this of course using the similar events. Not necessarily, but it would make it more efficient to wait for a second to avoid checking on every key input.

Comment: I do this with a BackGroundWorker that waits for 1 second and cancels on any keystroke but based sorry you need to show more effort.  What if there is a directory with a longer name that matches.

Comment: @Blam wow, perfect, I will try it, if works will put complete code here. Yes, that's true what if there is more to the directory, may be then I can add something more to the `BackGroundWorker` like every time when it will be invoked, if the check fails it will disable the button or do something opposite to the one I need if succeeds. Ultimately everything will be depending on the `Exist()` check.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining an arbitrary time, like 1 second, how about just looking for some application idle time?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx

You can put an event handle for `Application.Idle` event and check if the `TextBox` has user inputted values, and process it accordingly.

Comment: Great, this sounds nice approach to deal with this, I will give it a try, if works will post complete code here.